# Update an Opportunity from a future callout method

Tags: trigger, dml, future, update, dmlexception

I have a future method that posts data to an API, and IF the response2.getStatusCode() == 200, I would like to update a field on the opportunity. However, I get this error message:

*System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0068K0000060K8RQAU; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, opportunityOwnerAlert: execution of BeforeUpdate*

The code:

```
@future (callout=true)
public static void checkExist(String oppId){
Opportunity oppToUpdate = [Select Id, customCheckbox__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: oppId];

------------ 1st HTTP REQUEST DONE HERE ------------ 

 If(the response from the 1st HTTP is empty){
   ----- 2nd HTTP REQUEST ----
  if(response2.getStatusCode() == 200){
   oppToUpdate.customCheckbox__c = true;
   update oppToUpdate;
  }
 }
}
```

Also including my trigger:

```
trigger opportunityOwnerAlert on Opportunity (before insert,before update) {
Id[] oppList = new List<Id>();
    if(trigger.isBefore && (trigger.IsInsert || trigger.IsUpdate) && lightningStep.isFirstTime){
        lightningStep.isFirstTime = false; //prevents recursion
        for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){
            if(opp.stagename == 'VoB Pending' && opp.Push_To_Lightning_Step__c == True){
                    oppList.add(opp.Id);
            }
        }
    }
     if(!oppList.isEmpty()) {
             lightningStep.Sendtest(oppList);
        }

}
```

Comment: I think you've left off an important part of the error message. Please edit your question to include the entirety of the error message (and the stack trace).